# Commuting relation between riesz isomorphisms and pushforward/pullback

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

my book on geometric analysis states that given two sets $ X_0, X_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and a diffeomorphism $\varphi$ between them, the diagram

[image]

is commutative. $\Omega(X_i)$ are the differential forms on $X_i$ and $\Theta_i:X_i \rightarrow \Omega(X_i)$ are the riesz isomorphisms defined by $\theta_i v(w)= (v | w)$.

Trying to verify this relation i get that the differential of $\varphi$ has to be self-adjoint as a necessary condition, that is $\partial_j \varphi^k $ = $\partial_k (\varphi^{-1})^j$. With matrices this means the transpose is the inverse, but something like $x\mapsto \lambda x$ would already be a counterexample. I get this out when checking for $((\varphi^{-1})^*\Theta_0)(e_j)(f_k)=(\Theta_1\varphi_*)(e_j)(f_k)$ (with $e_j, f_k$ basis vectors, because of linearity this is equivalent to the statement).

Am i wrong or could this be true? If im wrong, could someone post the correct calculation for me?

Comment: This seems seriously wrong.  Yes, if you have a map between two manifolds, you get a pullback map on the ring of differential forms. Thus, if you have a diffeomorphism, you can go forward by pulling back by the inverse map. But I have no idea what your "Riesz isomorphism" is supposed to be. And what do you mean by "the differential forms on $X$"?

Comment: Intuitively the upper line reads more like $\mathcal{C}^\infty(X_i,\mathbb{R}^n)$, the space of vector fields on $X_i$, than $X_i$ itself. Since given a Riemannian metric $g$ there is a Riesz-duality between vector fields and $1$-forms, which is exactly given by $\theta(V):=g(V,\cdot)$, for any vector field $V$. Also push-forward (pull-back) is a natural operation for vector fields (1-forms resp.), but not for sets.

Comment: i did a mistake in the diagram and domain of the riesz isomorphism. you have to replace $X_i$ with the set of vector fields on $X_i$ (my vector fields are maps $X \rightarrow TX$, with $v(x)\in T_xX$, $TX$ is the tangent bundle and $T_xX$ the tangent space in $x\in X$). we can restrict $\Omega(X)$ to only contain oneforms for the theorem, which in my book are defined as maps $\alpha:X \rightarrow T^*X$ (cotangent bundle) with $\alpha(x)\in T^*_xX$ (cotangent space in $x$). the riesz isomorphism then maps a vector field $v$ to the form $x \mapsto (w \mapsto (v(x)|w)$, with $w\in T_xX$.

Comment: @dennis_s yes, this should be the generalization. i will look over my calculation again then.

Comment: @dennis_s i looked over it multiple times, still get the orthogonality condition. do you have a proof?

Comment: @depletedboi I get the same result that $d\varphi$ has to be self-adjoint (or to be more precise, that $\varphi$ has to be an isometry).

Comment: What does it mean for a linear map between *different* inner product spaces to be self-adjoint?

Comment: @TedShifrin In the case that the submanifolds are equipped with different inner products this reformulates to $\varphi$ being an isometry, i.e. $g(V,W)=\tilde{g}(d\varphi(V),d\varphi(W))$ for all $V,W$ vector fields on $X_0$.

Comment: I've never heard of self-adjoint maps between *different* vector spaces, and I've been around mathematics for 50 years. This entire question seems fraught with sloppiness/errors.

Comment: @TedShifrin True. There is no such notion. I should have been "only" precise.

Answer (score 1):

This statement is only true for isometries $\varphi:(X_0,g_0)\rightarrow (X_1,g_1)$ where $g_0,g_1$ are non-degenerate inner products on $X_0, X_1$ corresponding to $\theta_0,\theta_1$. Since $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism, we have an isomorphism $(d\varphi)^{-1}_*:\mathcal{C}^\infty(X_1,\mathbb{R^n})\rightarrow\mathcal{C}^\infty(X_0,\mathbb{R^n})$ and the statement reads as follows
\begin{align*} (d\varphi^{-1})^*\circ \theta_0\circ d\varphi^{-1}_*=\theta_1. \end{align*}
Take any vector field $V_1\in \mathcal{C}^\infty(X_1,\mathbb{R^n})$. Then by computation we have
\begin{align*} (d\varphi^{-1})^*\circ \theta_0\circ d\varphi^{-1}_*(V_1)=(d\varphi^{-1})^*\circ g_1((d\varphi^{-1})(V_1),\cdot)=g_1((d\varphi^{-1})(V_1),(d\varphi^{-1})(\cdot))\overset{!}{=}g_0(V_1,\cdot). \end{align*}
That is the defining condition for $\varphi$ to be an isometry.

Comment: very clear, thanks! so its indeed an error in the book

Comment: @depletedboi Great. If it helped you, you can accept the answer so that the question is closed.